# How to get printer properties

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, printer, automation

I need to generate a JPOS for a printer, however every printer has a unique String identifier that goes into the JPOS generation. I want to know if there's a way to get this property String through a command

So the image shown displays the Printer Properties, Hardware, Details, and the Property: Last known parent. This is where the String resides.

This seems to match whats in the generated JPOS(as highlighted), however to automate this we need to get the String in Properties through a command.

[image]